# Android Customized ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am having a Srollview in for my entire layout.In that i added a listview.when i scrolling the page ,tha page scrolls normally,but when it reaches listview listview only scrolls how to overcome this problem.

Please any one can suggest the answer.

I am looking that when i scroll the listview the whole page gets scrolled.

Comment: You should post your layout file

Comment: it is not recommanded to put a ListView ( scrollable view) inside of a ScrollView ( another scrollable view ). For customizing listView , check this tutorial : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/770/create-custom-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what it is exactly that you want, but never put a ListView inside a ScrollView! ListView does its own scrolling.